# SQL Server 2017 database should be split into two databases reg client data

Tags: sql-server

We have SQL Server 2017 on linux in which one client database is there. The client has informed us that the company will be split into two entities, so the database should be split into two as well; one database should hold the one entity's data and the other one should hold the other entity's data.

Existing data of one database should be split into the two databases. Could you please suggest in addressing this and what are the ways to achieve this?

Comment: I would think you need to write a script or a program...having expected results.

Comment: Is the client explicitly asking you to split the data into two databases, or do you just need a way to differentiate between the two entities? Multi-tenant databases aren't uncommon. You need to understand _exactly_ what the client's separation requirements are - logical, physical, or all the way to having their data on separate servers?

Comment: This is not a good question for Stack Overflow, because it’s not a SQL Server question but a data analysis problem. You need an expert on the application, and/or a consultant. There is no sensible answer without a detailed understanding of the application and data model. In a complex and not well documented application this can take weeks to months of work. If the data is subject to data privacy laws, a mistake can leave your organization subject to hefty fines. Some data cannot be disassociated easily (e.g. do you store a binary image that includes data from both entities? Is that OK?)

Comment: Alroc, client is asking explicitly to split the database into two,few employees will be migrated to new database and employee should be in one of this database not on two databases. few employees and their data will be migrated into new database and both databases can be resided on the same server

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to split a client database it to make two copies, and delete the each client's data from the other.  And, you'll need to ask, but in a scenario like this it's not always necessary to delete the older data from either database.  In which case you can just create two copies and let them diverge going forward.

Comment: Thanks David Browne for your quick reply, correct me if i am wrong you mean to say that create a copy of existing database then we should delete one client data from the other and vice versa

Comment: Thanks David Browne for your quick reply, correct me if i am wrong you mean to say that create a copy of existing database then we should delete one client data from the other and vice versa... what are the things we need to take care of while doing this? and can you just give brief view about how effectively we can delete the other client data and how to segregate the employees between this two databases, what are the steps.. it would be great if you can assist me on this

Comment: You'll have to ask your client and your developers about this.  It's very application-specific, and depends on how your client is splitting up.  You might start by proposing starting with two copies and _not deleting anythiing_.  If there are objections to that plan, ask what kinds of things need to be deleted from the new databases.

Comment: adding to this, the request from the client is one entity should not hold another entity data.